# How do I send dynamic key pair values to PHP with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some jQuery code that sends data to a PHP function, and some of the data that will be sent is key => value pairs.

The way I am doing it now is I am setting a variable to `[]` and then pushing `{'string1':'string2'}`, then sending this variable in.

So like this:

```
$(".test-button").click( function() {
        var inputData = [];
        $('.input-data').each(function( index ) {
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var value = $(this).val();
            inputData.push( { name : value } );
        });
var data = {
            testData: inputData
        };
```

When I get the data in PHP, if what I'm sending is 3 key value pairs, then the print_r output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 3
        )

)
```

What I'd really like is on the PHP side to just do something like

```
foreach($myInputData as $key => $value)
{
   $output .= $key . " : " . $value . " ";
}
```

I am a bit confused as to how to do this easy in jQuery/JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your javascript object, `name` is being treated as a literal, it's not using the variable you defined previously. You can do `inputData.push( { [name] : value } );` instead. 
This will create a new object each time and add it to the array, but you seem to be looking for a solution that sends just an object:

```
var inputData = {};
$('.input-data').each(function(index) {
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  var value = $(this).val();
  inputData[name] = value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try below code.

```
    $(".test-button").click( function() {
        var inputData = {};
        $('.input-data').each(function( index ) {
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var value = $(this).val();
            inputData[name] = value;
        });

    var data = inputData;
```